# AngularJS and Socket.IO model not being updated in event

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

This is my controller.

```
  app.controller('ChatController', function ()
  {
    this.username = '';

    this.setUsername = function (username)
    {
      this.username = username;
    };

    socket.on('success', (function (controller)
    {
      return function(username)
      {
        $('#password_page').fadeOut();
        controller.setUsername(username);
        $('#chat_page').removeClass('hidden').show();
      };
    })(this));
  });
```

And the problem is that when the event 'success' fires with the username correclty passed as an argument, the `this.username` in my controller doesn't get updated.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular doesn't know about soketio events, and hence doesn't run digest cycle when it happens. You need to manually trigger this process:

```
app.controller('ChatController', function ($scope) {
    this.username = '';

    this.setUsername = function (username) {
        this.username = username;
    };

    socket.on('success', (function (controller) {
        return function (username) {
            $('#password_page').fadeOut();
            controller.setUsername(username);
            $('#chat_page').removeClass('hidden').show();
            $scope.$apply();
        };
    })(this));
});
```

Regarding another problem in your code. I recommend get rid of jQuery in your project or at least limit its usage to directives only, more Angular-way. Lines like:

```
$('#password_page').fadeOut();
```

are not very good approach with Angular app. Use [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)/[ngHide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) directives instead.